# Video with overlay and logo using DFP for small business

Tags: ads, google-dfp, vast

I have got a requirement wherein I need to achieve:

- An overlay click on 320x250 ad inventory (with click tag and vast tag
  separately)
- A logo along on an Interstitial video inventory (with a      tag for
  logo and a vast tag separately)

The client wants that the whole video should not be clickable and only the overlay or the logo should be clickable.

How can I achieve the same using DFP for small business? Please help.